How can I integrate user login with Swagger?
I want to have a login functionality in Swagger. I was able to make appear a login button but it doesn't work. First of all it asks for client id and client secret but I don't have a secret for that client id. And when I write something random in the it returns the following error Auth Error[invalid_request]: Missing+parameter:+code_challenge_method.
I use org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.6.0.
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.*;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringdocConfiguration {

    private static final String OAUTH_SCHEME = "auth";

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    String authURL;

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Application"))
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement()
                        .addList(OAUTH_SCHEME))
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(OAUTH_SCHEME, createOAuthScheme()))
                .info(new Info());
    }

    private SecurityScheme createOAuthScheme() {
        return new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.OAUTH2).flows(createOAuthFlows());
    }

    private OAuthFlows createOAuthFlows() {
        final var oauthFlow = new OAuthFlow()
                .authorizationUrl(authURL + "/protocol/openid-connect" + "/auth")
                .refreshUrl(authURL + "/protocol/openid-connect" + "/token")
                .tokenUrl(authURL + "/protocol/openid-connect" + "/token")
                .scopes(new Scopes());
        return new OAuthFlows().authorizationCode(oauthFlow);
    }
}

Normally my login page goes to
https://user.example.com/auth/realms/om-test-dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=om-test-dev&state=VGVpN351Z3ZJLS1jYksuUnNjUzFDZHdUSEh3ZmVSTGpMeC5yaS5jck13SnMtsemicolon%252Fuser-dashboard&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.example.com%2Fhome&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access&code_challenge=Nuk3JzAnPRtg9Mmxiok26kj3qCQ_0H87T-PB5VgIPVw&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=VGVpN351Z3ZJLS1jYksuUnNjUzFDZHdUSEh3ZmVSTGpMeC5yaS5jck13SnMt

but if I write something random to the client id and client secret in the Swagger it goes to
https://user.example.com/auth/realms/om-test-dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.example.com%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fswagger-ui%2Foauth2-redirect.html&state=VGh1IE9jdCAyNCAyMDI0IDE2OjA4OjM5IEdNVCswMzAwIChFYXN0ZXJuIEV1cm9wZWFuIFN1bW1lciBUaW1lKQ%3D%3D

where you can see that it has some missing parameters. What I can do to add those missing parameters or what I can do to make login button redirect Swagger to my login page correctly?
